Why do the std::ranges algorithms have overloads for taking iterator-sentinel pairs?
I'm currently designing an API for a new library, trying to model it after the std::ranges algorithms. I notice that in addition to taking ranges as parameters, these functions have overloads to allow iterator-sentinel pairs to be supplied. For example, reverse_copy has both reverse_copy(I first, S last, O result) and reverse_copy(R&& r, O result). I would have thought that only the second form was necessary. Was the first form just added for compatibility with legacy systems, or is there some other reason that I might want to consider adding something analogous in my own designs?

Performing operations on a sub-range is still a valid workflow, and if std::ranges are to be adopted, they should support that workflow.

If you look at the Possible Implementation of reverse_copy you'll see that the one taking a range just calls the version taking iterators - so it's usually not much work involved.

it also lets you easily do using std::ranges::algo_name in place of using std::algo_name and still have your code work but also use the new hotness.

@sweenish doesn't std::ranges::subrange fulfil this need?

@NathanOliver That seems like the most plausible explanation. If that is indeed the only reason it was added, then there shouldn't be a need to supply something analogous in my library since there are no existing clients of my library.

@TedLyngmo yes, adding support for it in my library is easy. What I'm wondering is whether it actually makes sense to add it.

Passing a pair of iterators is a pretty natural thing to do for C++ programmers, it's been the way <algorithm> has worked since 1998.  For me its so ingrained I wouldn't even think about a subrange adaptor but would want to call the function with the iterator pair like I am always used to doing.  I would prefer any range like library I use allow both the range and the iterator pair for ease of use and convenience.

@NathanOliver: history is for me a wrong reason... For example, output parameters was the way to go before move semantic, but I would considering a mistake to providing a version like that in modern code.

"taking pairs of iterators"  They take an iterator and a sentinel, making them more powerful than the older algorithms in the std namespace.  Although that doesn't disqualify your std::ranges::subrange comment.

Thanks @DrewDormann! I updated it to "iterator-sentinel pair" instead.

@NathanOliver that only works if you are ignoring the returned values, as std::ranges::algo gives you back all the iterators it advanced, whereas std::algo only gives you the output iterator.

It's arguably easier to specify things in terms of [first, last), and then say "Same as (1), but uses r as the source range, as if using ranges::begin(r) as first and ranges::end(r) as last."
